# Create Github Actions dashboard

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, github-actions, monitoring

Is there a way to crease a summary dashboard for all my Github actions. This is something we had with Jenkins. We could see all deployment status on a single page.

From my research I found that there are tools out there like: ccmenu, nevergreen and so on but I am not too convinced about them.

I think, that I have seen some solutions for "system" status that include the CI portion but I cannot remember and Google is not helping me a lot.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

In GitHub, you either get a status badge from your builds which would be generated as:

```
https://github.com/<OWNER>/<REPOSITORY>/actions/workflows/<WORKFLOW_FILE>/badge.svg
```

Or by clicking the options menu on your workflow page:

[image: Create GH workflow badge]

[image: customize badge]

Then you can use these badges in your dashboard.

---

Also, with the new update you can create Job summaries:

```
jobs:
  foo:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Something
        ...
      - name: Generate list using Markdown
        run: |
          my_table="
          | Column1     | Status             | Something |
          |-------------|--------------------|-----------|
          | :octocat:   | :white_check_mark: | Passed    |
          | :honey_pot: | :x:                |           |
          "
          echo "# This is an example" >> $GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY
          echo "Using \`markdown\`" >> $GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY
          echo "$my_table" >> $GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY
```

Result:

[image: workflow summary page]

Then you can use one last action to write/emit your Github run URL for example to your dashboard.

See:

- https://github.blog/2022-05-09-supercharging-github-actions-with-job-summaries/
- https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#adding-a-job-summary
- https://docs.github.com/en/actions/monitoring-and-troubleshooting-workflows/adding-a-workflow-status-badge

---

Other than that, I don't think that we can answer with recommendations for tools and products that may do that for you. But seems that the tools you found may do the job very well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have also considered the badge approach but it does not seem to be quite right also.

Comment: Unfortunately looks like such features is [still on Github's roadmap](https://github.com/github/roadmap/issues/653) and not yet ready. And it might be against SoF ToC to ask about recommendations for tools. So I suggest just Google for "Alternative to [ONE OF THE TOOLS YOU FOUND]" there are plenty of third-party tools which they might be better than these 2 limited options from Github

Comment: Or maybe you can have a look at [Github deployments](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/deployments/deployments?apiVersion=2022-11-28) as they will show status items on your repository page